# Code always doing the same path regardless of input. (PYTHON)

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I'm currently writing a program for a school project.

The purpose is for it to work as an online cash register.

```
answer = "a"
qty1 = 0


while True:
    answer = str(input("\nDo you really wish to buy this? (Y/N) "))
    if answer == "Y" or "y":
        qty1 = int(input("\nHow much quantity of this item would you like to buy? "))
        print("\nDo you really wish to buy", qty1, "pieces? (Y/N) ")
        answer = str(input(""))
        if answer == "Y" or "y":
            print("Confirming order and returning to menu.")
            break
        else:
            qty1=0
            print("Cancelling order and returning to menu")
            break
        
    elif answer == "N" or "n":
        print("Okay, returning to menu.")
        break
    else:
        print("not valid answer")
```

Here is the code for the part of the program I'm having trouble with.

Whenever I reach this part of the program, the input seems to ignore whatever I put and it always goes through the if path.

Does anyone know why this is?

I'm new to programming, so sorry if this is just an easy fix.

Comment: Hint: `if answer == "Y" or "y":` does not do what you think it does.  Try `if answer in ("Y", "y")` instead.

Comment: This is getting to be one of the more common questions.  The expression `answer == 'Y' or 'y'` is parsed as `(answer == 'Y')  or 'y'`, and since `y` is always true, the `if` will be taken.  What you want is `if answer in ('Y','y'):`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: `print:("Cancelling order and returning to menu")` - there's a colon in there.

Comment: Whoops, it's been corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working code which needed some formatting:

Changed these lines -> `answer in ("Y", "y")` and `answer in ("N", "n")`.  This is because `if answer == 'Y' or 'y'` is used then `'y'` will always evaluate to `True` which means the first `if` statement always executes. Also, the error in the `print` statement has a colon: `print:` - this was corrected.

```
answer = "a"
qty1 = 0


while True:
    answer = str(input("\nDo you really wish to buy this? (Y/N) "))
    print(answer)
    if answer in ("Y", "y"):
        qty1 = int(input("\nHow much quantity of this item would you like to buy? "))
        print("\nDo you really wish to buy", qty1, "pieces? (Y/N) ")
        answer = str(input(""))
        print(answer)
        if answer in ("Y", "y"):
            print("Confirming order and returning to menu.")
            break
        else:
            qty1=0
            print("Cancelling order and returning to menu")
            break
        
    elif answer in ("N" ,"n"):
        print("Okay, returning to menu.")
        break
    else:
        print("not valid answer")
```

Comment: nit: It is more Pythonic to use `if answer in ("Y", "y")` instead.  It would also benefit the OP and future users that come here to *explain* what was wrong and how you corrected it.  Simply providing an answer is not useful to anyone but the OP.  We are here to build a community and archive of answers that long transcend after we pass on :).

Comment: Edited the code